# how to go back to normal when clicked outside ? [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter

I was just testing some features in javascript and css filters. So I just created three specific buttons and when I click on one of them the filters on the image change to 30%. So what I wanna do here is that when I click outside of the button it should turn to normal again. Please do help.

[image]

Here is jS code so far :

```
const br = document.getElementById("br");
const img = document.getElementById("test-img");

br.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    img.style.filter = "brightness(30%)";
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop event bubbling from buttons and reset on window click

```js
const br = document.getElementById("br");
const img = document.getElementById("test-img");

br.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  img.style.filter = "brightness(30%)";
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

window.onclick = function() {
  // code for resetting to normal
}
```

Comment: @Everyone using snippets: In the snippet editor there is a `tidy` button on the left side that automatically formats your code.

Comment: @Amit Mankotia Thanks that works great. btw i was just wondering is there any way i can do the same on off thing when the button is clicked again.Like first click gonna active the brightness and second click gonna reset it again

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to change something when a specific button is **not** clicked is to trigger the changes when anything on the document is clicked **except** the button:

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.id !== "#br") {
        removeVisualEffects(img);
    }
});

function removeVisualEffects(image) {
    image.style.filter = "none";
}
```

`e.target.id` is the element that launched the event: here that would be the element you clicked on.